Wrong time zone in Snowflake Java UDTF
In our Snowflake account, the time zone is set to America/New_York. There is a column in a table that is declared as DATE, so it does not store a time or time zone component. We pass values from that column into a Java UDTF, into a parameter declared as java.sql.Date. Let's assume that the DATE value is 2022-12-08.
A java.sql.Date represents a point in time, so we expected that the DATE column would be mapped as 2022-12-08 00:00:00.000 America/New_York, i.e., the original date value, at midnight, in the Snowflake account time zone. Instead, we are getting 2022-12-08 00:00:00.000 UTC, which in New York is a different date.
The Snowflake documentation says that the time zone setting is inherited from the database to the UDTF environment, so why is this happening? Why is a DATE converted to a java.sql.Date using the UTC time zone and not the Snowflake time zone?
To address some of the comments received here: we are using data types that are current, appropriate for our business, and supported according to Snowflake documentation: a Snowflake DATE column, which is appropriate because the time portion is not relevant to us, and which Snowflake maps to java.sql.Date when it passes the values to the UDTF. We are invoking a Java UDTF through a Snowflake function and therefore we have no control of how a Snowflake:DATE is passed in as a java.sql.Date.
We thought about converting the DATE to a TIMESTAMP_LTZ, so that we control the addition of a time/zone, but the TIMESTANP_LTZ maps to a java.sql.Timestamp, and we did not want to change the type of our UDTF input parameters (java.sql.Date).

Your problem is just as likely to be caused by using the obsolete java.util.Date, which alters its display depending on the user timezone, and as you say, does not represent a date, despite its name. A modern driver should support java.time.LocalDate, and you should call PreparedStatement::setObject and PreparedStatement::getObject when using it

We are not using java.util.Date. We are using java.sql.Date (which extends java.util.Date). We are also not using JDBC directly, since we are writing a Java UDTF. All the type conversions are handled by Snowflake, out of our control.

Yes, unfortunately, that's no better

@radumanolescu - regarding your first comment, explaining downvotes is not required.

This is not necessarily the best solution, but it's what we are doing as we wait for better ideas: we check each java.sql.Date value received and if it corresponds to "midnight in UTC" we transform it to "midnight in NYC on the same date". This works for us because the parameters to this UDTF are supposed to be dates (i.e. have no time/zone component) so if the time/zone are not "midnight in NYC" then they should be.
The clean solution would be for the Snowflake driver to offer a mapping from Snowflake:DATE (a data type without time/zone) to java.time.LocalDate, the obvious corresponding Java type. Until they do, we'll have to live with what is available: the DATE-to-java.sql.Date mapping.
public static ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUTC(Date date) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
    return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
}
public static boolean isUTC(Date date) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = zonedDateTimeUTC(date);
    return zdt.getHour() == 0 && zdt.getMinute() == 0 && zdt.getSecond() == 0 && zdt.getNano() == 0;
}
public static Date inNYC(Date date) {
    if (!isUTC(date)) return date;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = zonedDateTimeUTC(date);
    ZonedDateTime nyc = ZonedDateTime.of(zdt.getYear(), zdt.getMonthValue(), zdt.getDayOfMonth(),
            0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    return new Date(nyc.toEpochSecond() * 1000L);
}


I'm not quite convinced, for reasons I won't go in to yet. One thing is for certain and that is you should try to avoid obsolete classes. For one thing the driver itself will mutate Date  (see API docs) Therefore you should throw an exception probably if there is any time information in your Dates


Conceptually, a java.sql.Date is the same as a LocalDate, ie. a date without time or time-zone. In practice, because java.sql.Date is implemented based on a long milliseconds, it has an implicit use of the system time-zone. So, the toLocalDate() method exists because the Java SQL spec leads want you to think of java.sql.Date as being without a time-zone.

And I think that might confuse some users. At least in my test:
create or replace function date_test(d date)
returns table(output_value varchar)
language java
handler='TestFunction'
target_path='@~/TestFunction.jar'
as
$$
  import java.sql.Date;
  import java.util.stream.Stream;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

  class OutputRow {

    public String output_value;

    public OutputRow(String outputValue) {
      this.output_value = outputValue;
    }

  }


  class TestFunction {


    public TestFunction()  {
    }

    public static Class getOutputClass() {
      return OutputRow.class;
    }

    public Stream<OutputRow> process(Date d) {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
      String formatted = sdf.format(d);
      return Stream.of(new OutputRow(formatted));
    }

  }

$$;

And If I run:
select * from table(date_test(current_date))

It prints PDT as the timezone which in my case matches the account timezone.
So, it might be the way you are doing the date interpretation

Based on @oreballac's code, I tested my local timestamp with 3 different UDFs. The only way I could get a correct date out of a Java stored procedure while giving it a timestamp with timezone was to send it as a string, and parse the string internally with Java:
The 3 udfs:
create or replace function date_test(d date)
returns varchar
language java
handler='TestFunction.test'
as
$$
  import java.sql.Date;
  class TestFunction {
    public String test(Date d) {
      return d.toString();
    }
  }
$$;

create or replace function date_string_test(d varchar)
returns varchar
language java
handler='TestFunction.test'
as
$$
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  
  import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
  import java.util.Date;
  class TestFunction {
    public String test(String d) {
      return d;
    }
  }
$$;

create or replace function date_parse_and_output(d varchar)
returns date
language java
handler='TestFunction.test'
as
$$
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.text.ParseException;
  class TestFunction {
    public java.sql.Date test(String d) throws ParseException {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
      java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(d);
      return new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    }
  }
$$;


This is how I tested the code:
create or replace temp table dates_with_tz as
select '2024-04-01 15:12:42.327 -0700'::timestamp_tz ts;

select ts
    , date_test(ts)
    , date_string_test(ts)
    , date_parse_and_output(ts)
from dates_with_tz
;

On the results you can see that the naive function weirdly moves the date back one day, while parsing the string in Java with new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z") returns the correct date:



TS
DATE_TEST(TS)
DATE_STRING_TEST(TS)
DATE_PARSE_AND_OUTPUT(TS)





2024-04-01 15:12:42.327 -0700
2024-03-31
2024-04-01 15:12:42.327 -0700
2024-04-01




